# Support for url suffix in django

Tags: python, django, multi-tenant

I use [django-tenant-schemas](http://django-tenant-schemas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) and I need to change the way it selects the current tenant:

from https:// **tenant1**.mydomain.com/

to https:// mydomain.com/**tenant1**/

To do that I've coded a middleware, it's quite simple and it's working, the tenant is selected. The problem comes in the url resolution in django. It raises a 404 cause there is no url mapping that includes that suffix "tenant1".

How could I tell django that the urls now have a dinamic suffix that changes deppending on the tenant? This should be used reversing and generating urls.

Comment: Did you tried passing the tenant to reverse function as kwargs ?

Comment: In the project urls.py I've added a optional parameter for this tenant and it seems to resolve ok. But How could I change the generation of urls?

Comment: What do you mean by generation of urls ? Do you mean by using the django.urls.reverse() ?

Comment: For example the urls generated in the django admin, so they include the tenant suffix